# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Application.getProperties()Ljava/util/Map; when deploying jersey ws to Weblogic

Tags: java, web-services, jersey, weblogic, jax-rs

I'm deploying a web service application on Weblogic 12. The application uses jersey and thus depends on **javax.ws.rs-api:2.0.1** library.

However when I deploy it to server I have a following error :

```
Caused By: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Application.getProperties()Ljava/util/Map;
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:304)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:285)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:311)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:170)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:358)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:240)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:337)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:288)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
...
```

I think that weblogic might have it's own version of javax.ws.rs.core.Application that doesn't have this getProperties() method. I'm packaging the application in a WAR file and tried to use

```
  <container-descriptor>
    <prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>
  </container-descriptor>
```

in **weblogic.xml**, to explicitly tell Weblogic to use 2.0.1 version of this library.

Nothing helped so far, the issue still in place..

Thanks.

Comment: This is likely a class loading issue where the sun jersey client (1.x) is being loaded into memory prior to the newer jersey library (2.x).  I've had this problem when other utilities I use include jersey-client 1.x, but I've been able to exclude that dependency in my project build files.

Answer (score 6):

I found this to work as a solution. Add it in your weblogic.xml:

```
    <wls:container-descriptor>
    <wls:prefer-application-packages>
        <!--  jersey-bundle-*.jar-->
        <wls:package-name>com.sun.jersey.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>com.sun.research.ws.wadl.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>com.sun.ws.rs.ext.*</wls:package-name>

        <!-- Jackson-*.jar -->
        <wls:package-name>org.codehaus.jackson.*</wls:package-name>

        <!-- jettison-*.jar -->
        <wls:package-name>org.codehaus.jettison.*</wls:package-name>

        <!-- jsr311*.jar -->
        <wls:package-name>javax.ws.rs.*</wls:package-name>

        <!-- asm.jar -->
        <wls:package-name>org.objectweb.asm.*</wls:package-name>
    </wls:prefer-application-packages>
</wls:container-descriptor>
```

[Reference from Oracle Weblogic Documenation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24983/version.htm#RESTF201)

Comment: only

    `<!-- jsr311*.jar -->`
    `<wls:package-name>javax.ws.rs.*</wls:package-name> `

is needed for your error.

Comment: When I do this, my service ceases to work on WebLogic 12.2.1.3.0 (nothing shows in the logs, it just doesn't respond any more)